# How to retain set value on QSpinBox in QWidget when visiting this widget everytime?

Tags: c++, qt

I am having QSpinBox in QWidget where i set some value. Whenever i visit this widget next time, the spinbox takes initial value as zero instead of whatever value I set before.Is anyone having idea about it?

Thanks in advance.

Dialog:

```
Spin_Box::Spin_Box(QWidget parent) 
    : QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::Spin_Box) 
{ 
    ui->setupUi(this); 
    / Settings for title bar / 
    ui->headingTextEdit->setText("SPIN BOX"); 
    / Settings Range for Time spin boxes */ 
    ui->fromHourSpinBoxShift1->setRange(0,23); 
    ui->fromMinSpinBoxShift1->setRange(0,59); 
    ui->fromSecSpinBoxShift1->setRange(0, 59); 
}
```

Slot where dialog is opened:

```
MainWindow::on_actionSpin_Box_triggered()
{
    Spin_Box Spin_BoxDialogue; 
    Spin_BoxDialogue.setModal(true); 
    Spin_BoxDialogue.exec();
}
```

Comment: My suspicion is that you re-create it each time you "visit" the widget. Please show the corresponding code.

Comment: Is widget created each time you visit it? Try to hide widget instead of destroying it.

Comment: Spin_Box::Spin_Box(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::Spin_Box)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   
    /* Settings for title bar */
    ui->headingTextEdit->setText("SPIN BOX");

    /* Settings Range for Time spin boxes */
    ui->fromHourSpinBoxShift1->setRange(0,23);
    ui->fromMinSpinBoxShift1->setRange(0,59);
    ui->fromSecSpinBoxShift1->setRange(0, 59);
}

Comment: PLease add code where you call your widget.

Comment: void MainWindow::on_actionSpin_Box_triggered()
{
   
        Spin_Box Spin_BoxDialogue;
        Spin_BoxDialogue.setModal(true);
        Spin_BoxDialogue.exec();
}

Comment: How should i retain the same value @Robert?

Comment: Do you really need to create a new instance of the dialog each time? I usually hide a dialog if possible. You could use QSettings to store the previous values or some other mechanism depending on how long you want to retain the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make `Spin_BoxDialogue` a pointer to `Spin_Box` a member of your `MainWindow`. So "MainWindow.h" should have this line inside `class MainWindow`'s `private` section:

   Spin_BoxDialogue* m_foo;
2. Initialize it and set it to Modal in `MainWindow`'s constructor. Note that `Spin_BoxDialogue` should have a constructor that takes a pointer to its parent to take advantage of Qt's memory management.

   MainWindow::MainWindow() : m_foo(new Spin_BoxDialogue){m_foo->setModal(true);}
3. Then change `MainWindow::on_actionSpin_Box_triggered` to this:

   void MainWindow::on_actionSpin_Box_triggered(){m_foo->show();}

Comment: You could make a getter and setter to get and set the value of the spin box in the Spin_BoxDialogue that you call the setter (to set the value of the spin box to a saved value in your MainWindow) before setModal() and the getter after exec() to retrieve the value of the spinbox.

Comment: @Sanks I've changed my answer to more clearly specify what you need to do. This _will_ work, but I can understand it can be difficult to integrate with your code. If it's still not working for you, double check that the dialog isn't showing behind the main window. That shouldn't be happening, but I've seen it before. Baring that we can talk about some debug steps you can take.

Comment: it's giving me the error of "Spin_BoxDialogue does not a name type".

Comment: Right you'll need to `#include` your header file that defines `Spin_BoxDialogue`.

Answer (score 1):

As vahancho and Oleg Olivson stated in the comments, each time the function `on_actionSpin_Box_triggerd()` gets called a new instance of your Dialog is created. Therefore all values are those initialized.

If you want to keep previously inserted values you have to, either create the dialog only once (within your class where `on_actionSpin_Box_triggered()` is implemented) and reuse it by calling only `exec()` each time, or you store the values of the dialog in settings/... or whatever, to load them each time the dialog is opened.

Depending whether you would also need them after a program restarts, only the second approach would help.

Comment: Without looking at your code I wouldn't be able to answer to your question. Do you need further help?

Comment: I don't get you, where is there additional code? What do you want me to do?

Comment: @Sanks You have to make decisions on how you want to handle this. I mean again do you want the spin box value to be saved after closing the program. If not do you really need to recreate the dialog box every time when you could just hide it. If you do not need to recreate the dialog box the problem is already solved. If you do there are several methods to save values from a dialog box and restore them..

Comment: @drescherjm...Actaully I want to save the value. But if i want to change the value of spinbox next time then it has to retain the new value.

Comment: We understand that part. However you still did not answer the question on how you want this to work. Again does the value need to be saved if the application is closed and reopened does it need to restore the value from the last time you ran the application. If not you probably just need to hide the dialog.

Comment: I just gave you an alternate answer (that does not require hiding the box) in the other answer.